# Kill: invalid signal on AIX 7.1

Tags: shell, aix, kill

We recently upgrade from AIX 6.1 to AIX 7.1. We already had some shell scripts, to execute some kill procedures. After the migration we found an strange behaviour.

Our process calculate a parameter. In the program language that we use, the parameter has an "&" before the name. This program execute the send the following command to the server: "sudo kill -9 'fuser &parameter1/&parameter2".

Before the upgrade, even if the parameter not was resolved, the process continue. After we migrate to AIX 7.1 if for any reason de parameter is not resolve, then the following error appears:

*/usr/bin/ksh: parameter2:  not found
/: cccrrrrrcrcrrrrrrrrrcrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrcrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrccrrrrrrcrrrcrrrrrrrrccrrrcrrrcrc
kill: 1: invalid signal
kill: 44444: no such process*

After that, the server crash. No one can connect using PuTTY or FTP and the only solution is restart the server. Any idea what is the explanation of this behaviour?

We already add a line to only send the kill command if the parameter is resolved, but we'd like to understand what is going on.

Comment: You really shouldn't run known-to-be-broken scripts as super-user... You might have killed every running process that used the root-directory: `kill -9 ´fuser /´`

Comment: Also symbol `&` is a command-separator in shell, so this line might have started two or three commands paralelly, one killing everything, the other(s) being invalid doing nothing.